# What should I do with an old NEXUS card?

Tags: nexus

I have a NEXUS card that is no longer up-to-date.

Canada [says](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/term-eng.html) they must be destroyed

> If you are issued a new card, your previous card must be destroyed as it will no longer be valid.

How should I do this? Should CBP do it? Is cutting it up with scissors and throwing it in my garbage sufficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a family member lost and found a passport, I asked a CBSA officer at the Ottawa airport enrollment centre if Nexus cards should be treated the same (i.e. mailing it to Passport Protection). They said "treat it like a credit card; a couple snips should do."

While it's not official written/documented advice, it's good enough for me. A single small cut through the antenna is good enough to render the card functionally useless -- a few more for privacy (especially through the data area on the back) makes sense.